# getting a segmentation fault don't know how to fix it I know where it is

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am making a program to test the performance of running multiple threads vs one single thread. In this program I am running into a segmentation fault on line 26 which says `dataArray[i] = 0;`i have commented down below which line the error is on. The reason i know what line it is is because I put my code threw a debugger.

here is the full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// your custom calculation done on each index of the array 
inline int calcValue(int index)
{
  return index * 2  + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int N = 1000000;
  int *dataArray = new int[N];
  double timearray[100];
ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("data.csv");



 for(int a=0; a<100; a++)
 {
  // init array
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        dataArray[i] = 0;//error is here

  // traverse array and measure time
  struct timespec start, stop;

  //save start time 
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);

  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    dataArray[i] = calcValue(i); 

   //save end time 
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &stop);
  // calc elapsed time
  double cpuTime = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e6 + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e3;    // in micros
 timearray[a]=cpuTime;
  // report results
  cout<<"Start verify Calculation..."<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
      if(calcValue(i)!=dataArray[i])
      {
        cout<<"Bad value "<<dataArray[i]<<" at position "<<i<<endl;
        break;
      }
  }
  cout<<"End verify calculation"<<endl;
  cout<<"CPU time micro: "<<cpuTime<<endl;

  // cleanup
  delete []dataArray;
 }
 for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    myfile <<timearray[i]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: You delete the allocated memory inside the loop. After that you aren’t allowed to touch it and you do.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Haha I wonder how you veterans catch these things so fast!

Comment: I say experience.

Comment: Good judgment comes from experience, and experience — well, that comes from poor judgment!